# How type inference works when assuming collection types in swift

Tags: swift

```
var arrayorset=["0","1","21"]
```

Swift is type inference and type safety but how swift know the difference between the sets and array

it will be the problem when the array is needed instead of a set because sets are unordered list it cannot retrieve me list orderly

so how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the actual problem are you facing? Can you elaborate on the **input** & **output**?

Comment: no, I am not facing any problem, I am gathering  how swift works

Comment: If it's not specified `Array` will be inferred, if you want `Set` you must specify `Set`. If you want some other `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` type, you must specify that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... how swift know the difference between the sets and array ...

```
["0", "1", "21"]
```

is an *array literal,* and the type inference is documented with the [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) protocol (emphasis added):

> Arrays, sets, and option sets all conform to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral
>   ...
>    Because **Array is the default type** for an array literal, without writing any other code, you can declare an array with a particular element type by providing one or more values.

Therefore

```
let arrayOfStrings = ["0", "1", "21"]     // [String]
```

declares an array of strings, and an explicit type annotation is needed to declare a set of strings:

```
let setOfStrings: Set = ["0", "1", "21"]  // Set<String>
```

Note that `Set` is sufficient for the type annotation here, the element type `String` is inferred from the array literal.

Answer (score 1):

A set can be initialized with an array literal for convenience. To specify that you want a set instead of an array, you can annotate the type:

```
let array = ["0", "1", "21", "1"]
let set: Set<String> = ["0", "1", "21", "1"]
print(array)  // ["0", "1", "21", "1"]
print(set)    // ["0", "1", "21"]
```