# Swift - Declaring a Set using named variable

Tags: swift, set

I am trying to understand Sets in Swift and how to declare them correctly but I have found the following a little confusing.

I understand that this works:

```
let elements = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7]
let setFromElements = Set(elements)
```

But I don't understand why the following doesn't:

```
let setFromElements : Set = elements
```

Or even:

```
let setFromElements : Set<Int> = elements
```

When the following is valid:

```
let setFromArray : Set = [ 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is the case?

Comment: `Set(elements)`, that's calling in fact `Set(_ sequence: elements)`  in fact, that's why it works.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/initialization-with-literals

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53776199/1187415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let setFromArray: Set = [ 1, 2, 4, 5]` works because `Set` conforms to [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) and hence has an initializer that takes an `ArrayLiteral`. See [`Set.init(arrayLiteral:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2945904-init). This conformance gives syntactic sugar for not having to explicitly call the init.

On the other hand, once you save the array literal into a variable using `let elements = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6, 7]`, `elements` becomes an `Array`, not an `ArrayLiteral` and hence another initializer of `Set` has to be called that takes an `Array`. This init does not provide syntactic sugar like `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` does, so you explicitly have to call the init by doing `Set(array)`.

Answer (score 0):

Set has an *initializer that takes an array*, and that makes a set, by taking the unique items in the array.  But *a set* is not *an array*, two different types, so you can't just use `=` to assign one to the other.

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely forgot that the types have an initialiser to convert from one type to another.